# Can't apply patches from git repo to empty git repo

Tags: git, patch

In an effort to open-source a Minecraft project, I tried to extract the patches from the git repo for it. This way people with a MCP instance could apply the patches and get the source code without breaking copyright.

I can not apply all of the patches. I keep getting patches that do not apply cleanly with my standard git repo. Patches are pulled out of it and applied to a blank repo. I've tried using `git apply ../patches/* .` and `git am ../patches/* .`, but neither of these do the job. Is there something I am missing or is this just an issue with the commits on the repo I'm trying to manipulate? Is there something that is flawed with this approach in the first place?

I've also tried doing this with a few other repositories for unrelated things, and they also can not generate the source from all of the commits, which would push me towards guessing that this is an issue with something I'm doing and not the repo. (I've seen this done with SpigotMC for the same reason, so I have no reason to believe it's impossible.)

Comment: As a test, what happens if you use the `patch` command instead to try to apply the failing patches?

Comment: Seems to work a bit better, but some still fail. (I made a little script to go through all of them with `patch -p1 < [filename]` incrementally)

Edit: I think part of it might be possibly that it's failing GIT binary patches? But going the other route with git apply just fails perfectly fine patches without binary (as I described)

Comment: I can't make sense of the question: in particular, Git can't apply a patch to an empty repository as there are no commits yet, and a patch (especially one made to use with `git am`) generally has to start with an existing commit. Perhaps if you described your process in more detail...?

Comment: So, the patch isn’t made with git am, it’s a bunch of patches, all of the ones for the git repo (minus the initial one where I added the copyrighted source code in question) TL;DR, I’m trying to apply all of the commit patches (generated with: `git format-patch -o patches --root HEAD`) from a github repo (onto a blank repo) to obtain the full source code.